# D3 graph generation with range in x axis

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to generate a graph in D3 with data as json. The concept is to show the time taken by each developer in a project. In this, I have to show a bar graph generating from the json data which is using for plotting start week and end week on 'x axis' and developer name on 'y axis'. Also on tooltip, I have to show other relevant details for each developer.

I'm unable to generate this graph properly using  start week and end week in 'x axis'. I'm looking for support from d3 developer community. Thank You.

[image]

Comment: I created an example a while ago that does something similar, take a look at http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/1962173. I used a time scale for my axis, but you can just swap it out for a linear scale instead.

Comment: Thank You @Bill let me check.